# Android change Action Bar icon position

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have created an Action bar like the following.

[image]

The program language is RTL. I have changed it using the following code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void forceRTLIfSupported()
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
}
```

And used the following code in `onCreate()`:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_icon);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("سیکاس");
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff378417));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

The yellow icon is a `Drawable`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:left="8dp" />

</layer-list>
```

How can I make the make the Yellow Icon appear on the left side of the Action bar?

Answer (score 1):

Add custom layout for the actionbar,

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
LayoutInflater mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_custom_view, null);

toolbar.addView(mCustomView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:gravity="left"
```

with

```
android:gravity="end"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. seems like `android:gravity` doesn't work at all here.